# process group A default route tun0, B default route tun1, etc

Tags: linux, tunneling, network-namespace

I have a Linux box with *N* tunnel interfaces, `tun0`, `tun1`, and so on.

I want to set things up so that a particular group of processes, *A*, has its default (and only) route pointed at `tun0`. Meanwhile, a second group of processes, *B*, has its default (and only) route pointed at `tun1`, and so on. *A*, *B*, and so on are not necessarily "process groups" in the POSIX sense; ideally, the configuration would be established in advance, after which, any process could declare itself a member of *A* or *B* or ... at startup.  (It is okay if only processes running as `root` can do that.)

It is a bug if any of these groups of processes ever sends traffic out the wrong tunnel interface, or out the real network interface `eth0`.  It is also a bug if unrelated processes on the same host ever send traffic out *any* of the tunnel interfaces; they should continue to use `eth0` directly.

I have the impression that this can be done with "network namespaces" but I have been unable to figure out how; I am asking for step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can indeed be done with network namespaces.  Assume that you have all of the following information (which is either assigned by the process at the other end of the tunnel device, or by your controller program):

- `$namespace` a label for the network namespace
- `$device`    the tunnel device to be assigned to the namespace
- `$mtu`       the MTU for the tunnel device
- `$address`   the IP address to assign to the tunnel device
- `$netmask`   the netmask to assign to the tunnel device
- `$broadcast` the broadcast address to assign to the tunnel device
- `$gateway`   the default gateway to use inside the namespace
- `$dns_servers`  a list of DNS servers to use inside the namespace

Then the following pseudo-shell-script will set up the namespace:

```
mkdir /etc/netns/$namespace
for dns_server in $dns_servers {
    echo "nameserver $dns_server" >> /etc/netns/$namespace/resolv.conf
}

ip netns add $namespace
ip link set dev $device netns $namesapce

ip netns exec $namespace {
    ip link set dev lo up
    ip addr add dev $device local $address/$netmask broadcast $broadcast
    ip link set dev $device mtu $mtu up
    ip route add default via $gateway dev $device
}
```

And to tear it down again, you do

```
kill $(ip netns pids $namespace)
ip netns delete $namespace
rm -rf /etc/netns/$namespace
```

And to run a program inside the namespace, just use `ip netns exec`.

An actual working implementation of this mechanism for OpenVPN tunnels may be found [here](https://github.com/zackw/tbbscraper/blob/master/scripts/openvpn-netns.c); unfortunately, because for what *I* need it for it has to be setuid, the above turns into 1200 lines of C.